# Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources' android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't run my android studio project because of this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
> Failed to parse XML file 'C:\Users\black\AndroidStudioProjects\StockProfit\app\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\xml\data_extraction_rules.xml'

also same error with short message:

> Premature end of file.

my tried solutions but did not work:

- deleted build folder
- invalidated cache
- cleaned and rebuild project
- updated the application and packages
- increased memory in gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

`Premature end of file` suggests that the file is not a properly formatted XML file, the file is empty, the file cannot be read, or less likely, the file does not exist.

Have you tried opening the file `(C:\Users\black\AndroidStudioProjects\StockProfit\app\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\xml\data_extraction_rules.xml)` in Android Studio and checking its formatting?

I'm not sure if it is required here, but some compilers/parsers require a trailing carriage return as the last character of the file.

Comment: it is empty. even if I delete it or copy content from other project. it generates new empty one.

Comment: Ok. Usually, all contents of the build folder are generated from a compile command. So it makes sense that it gets overwritten. Do you have a data source fragment (old data source you have now deleted) or did you try to add a data source that is not complete? Perhaps you can explore the gradle files for clues? "Resources" is another clue, did you modify the default Android resources?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what do you mean by data source fragment...I created activity in wrong folder then moved it...then got weird issues like messed up theme and crashes.. so deleted everything and redownloaded my source code from github and extracted in same folder....then got this issue

Comment: thank you solved the issue and posted the answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

found empty xml file and I did not how it happned to be there it is called: data_extraction_rules.xml in res folder

it is empty so removed it. done.